# Synchronisation between Video and UI/Image editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am a  fresh Blender user. I started collecting training videos and some of them are very explanatory indeed. So I guessed, following their instructions I could manage. The problem I describe here is a problem I have with all the videos I shot with my Panasonic Camcorder  HC-VX870.

In this video, wanted to blur the ship floating on the river Seine.

System imformation :
Computer ASUS Desktop PC P30AD
Processor 4 Intel Core i3-4160 CPU @ 3,60 Ghz
Memory : 3914 MB
OS : Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Specs of the video :
Duration :  1 minute 24 seconds
Container : Quicktime

Video :
Dimensions : 3840 x 2160
Codec : H.264 (High profile)
Frame rate : 25 fps
Bit rate : 61128 kbps

Audio :
Codec : MPEG4-AAC
Channels : Stereo
Sample rate : 48000 Hz
Bit rate : 256 kbps

Media details
Demuxer : lavfpref

Let us now take a look at  the process itself.

Step 1 : I add the video. It appears in the upper-right side window. Everything works fine.

Step 2 :  I open the UV Image Editor in the upper-left side window . OK.

Step 3 : I create my mask (upper-ledt side window). I call it Blur_01. OK.

Step 4 : In the Upper-left side window, I open the video. It appears. No sinc yet, but so far, so good.

Step 5 : In the Upper-left side window, I select View/Properties, in order to sync the left side and right side.
[image: ![file:///home/olivier/Pictures/05_SelectProperties.jpg]

Step 6 :   In the Upper-left side window, I now tick  the Match movie length and Auto Refresh boxes… and the video disappears.
[image: ![file:///home/olivier/Pictures/06_MatchMovieLength.jpg]

I have been trying hard over the past week to solve this problem, to little avail, so I am turning to you now.

I also tried on Blender 2,76. I managed to move my mask around in the UV Image Editor, then I ended up with two cases :

- If I start from image 1 (say image 1 to image 50), everything seems t work fine and I manage to get full sync (i.e. the mask  moves around nicely in both windows).
- If I start from another image (say image 51 to 100), then I cannot get the sync and, while the mask moves around in the Upper-left side window, it stays stuck at image 51 in the Upper -right side window.

I hope I clearly stated the nature of my problem. Thanking you in advance for your time and efforts.

Comment: It could really help if you try with the last version 2.78c because it could be a bug.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Actually, the version I am using is already 2.78c. Indeed, I had not noticed the (little) c coming after '2.78' in the opening splash window.

Comment: I lately tried with version 2.79 and faced the same issue. Too bad, as Blender seems to be the software I need. Thanks for your time and effort anyway. I'll keep trying...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to convert the video to an image secuence, you can do it with Blender if you want, render the video without changes to a series of images. Anyway I prefer using `ffmpeg` to do this job, is free and you have lots of examples on Internet.

I think the problem could be that, as the video is encoded, a frame in the middle could not exist (completely) and this is why it can't show the image.

Comment: I just converted part of one of my videos (image 392 to 480) to an image (PNG) sequence. I got all the 89 frames complete, so none of them is missing. I did the same with another of my videos and again got a continuous sequence of PNG images, with none missing.

Comment: I also tried to convert some my *.mp4 videos into *.avi videos. It worked nicely but when I tried to apply the process I initially described, I ended up with the same issue.

Comment: @olivermassot the issue appears when you use the avi or the png sequence?

Comment: The issue appears when I use the avi format. Actually, sometimes the video simply does not appear on the Upper-left side window, or it freezes on one frame (as soon as I tick on the Match movie length box.

Comment: The problem with the avi is the same as you have before, encoded videos usually doesn't have all the frames as complete images and I always recommended to work directly with the image sequence strips.

Comment: I converted one of my mp4 video (4692 frames) into a sequence of 4692 PNG images. I managed to get full sync between the upper-right and left windows. So it works, but it is quite cumbersome.

Comment: Maybe you could submit a bug in Blender so they can improve it https://www.blender.org/support/